# SSIS - loop each row

Tags: ssis

I have a table and want to loop thru each rows.

select tablename from TableX

1. Created the Execute SQL task
2. Added the Foreach loop container.

So now I need to check the tablename and based on that I need to take action.

For example - when it returns "Tab1" called the Data Flow Task T1
when it returns "Tab2" call the DFT T2
and so on.

I am having trouble checking the value for tablename and calling the corresponding Data Flow Tasks.

Please help.
ramamosn

Answer (score 0):

if you have table names in table **TableX**.

1 Create record set

2 use for each loop and iterate throw result set and set veritable

3  Put all data flow inside loop container set variable vale to tablename   .

4 Expression set the properties Disable  and expression  variable value <> to table name .

below is sample link for record set

http://www.select-sql.com/mssql/loop-through-ado-recordset-in-ssis.html